# Best NES emulator?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, games, emulation

I have tried two emulators and Megaman 2 has issues running on GFCE Ultra NES Emulator where Megaman disappears when hit. GCEUX has sound problems.

Comment: Did you try changing ROM?

Does your ROM work flawlessy on another emulator (and operating system)?

Also tweaking your emulator configuration can make a HUGE difference.

Answer (score 2):

Since youve already tried those 2, I would recommend [fceux](http://fceux.com/web/home.html). It's from the same "family" of emulators you've tried, but a different branch. And it's in the official repositories. Maybe they have fixed your sound issue.

Comment: Stable and easy to install. Allows proper full screen unlike Nestopia.

Answer (score 0):

Try RockNES http://rocknes.kinox.org

Comment: i got it and extracted it, 'rocknes' is executable but clicking it does nothing.